# Where is the "MIMIC-III Waveform Database"?

Tags: mimic-iii

Can somebody help to clarify that if there is such thing as  "MIMIC-III Waveform Database" that is available for downloading? or this is the same thing as the mimic II waveform data available from here? 
https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/mimic2wdb/

I understand that the linkage between waveform and clinical data is not available for MIMIC III? but I am looking for the waveform database itself.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the MIMIC-III Waveform Database is not publicly available yet.